# How to add progress bar to an Imageview programmatically in android?

Tags: android, imageview, progress-bar

I have a class that extends Imageview. I need to add a progress bar to that ImageView programmatically.

This is my code:

```
public void viewPopup() {

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);


    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;

    if(isFullScreen()) {
        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(layout, (width), (height), true);
    }else {
        if (windowHeight != 0 || windowWidth != 0) {
            width = windowWidth;
            height = windowHeight;
            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(layout, (width), (height), true);
        } else {
            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(layout, (int) (width * .8), (int) (height * .6), true);
        }
    }


    popupWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    ImageView closeIcon = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.closeBtn);

    if (isHideCloseIcon()) {
        closeIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    closeIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }
    });

    if (isImageOnClickClose()) {
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                popupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    dimBehind(popupWindow);

}
```

I need to initialize the progress bar after the metrics and it should disappear after the image loads (i.e inside the popup window).

I tried this for initialization :

```
progressBar = new ProgressBar(activity, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
```

But I don't know how to proceed after this.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly do you want to achieve. In general ImageView isn't a container so you  couldn't add anything to it. It was created for display an image ;)

Comment: I added progressBar within the Glide command. It is working. Thanks for the reply :)